# How to create a function to parse a JSON block?

Tags: python

> With the below 'food_object' json block, create a function to parse the 'food_object' and provide the two variables 'desired_type' and 'desired_id' that will return the corresponding food to be returned, given provided desired type and id. With the returned result, print out the result in a string with the 'desired_type' variable in a format like this: 'My fruit's name is: apple"

```
food_object = {
    "fruit": [
        {
        "id": "001",
        "name": "apple"
    },{
        "id": "002",
        "name": "orange"
    },{
        "id": "003",
        "name": "banana"
    }
    ],
    "vegetable": [
        {
        "id": "001",
        "name": "carrot"
    },{
        "id": "002",
        "name": "broccoli"
    },{
        "id": "003",
        "name": "green beans"
    }
    ]
}

desired_type = "fruit"
desired_id = "001"
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `json` module ?

Comment: yes I am allowed to use the json module

Comment: Do you really have JSON (a text string), or do you have a nested data structure made of dicts and lists? If you call `type` on your `food_object`, does it return `str` or `dict`?

Comment: What you've posted is a bunch of dicts and lists, but it's hard to tell if that's what you have in your actual task.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `loads` from the `json` module to convert a JSON string to a dictionary, then loop over the items of the list `json[desired_type]` and check for each item if it's id matches the `desired_id`, if so, return that item's name. If there's no match, return something like `not found`. Then, use a `print` to print out the result:

```py
import json

desired_type = "fruit"
desired_id = "001"

json_string = """{
    "fruit": [
        {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "apple"
        },{
            "id": "002",
            "name": "orange"
        },{
            "id": "003",
            "name": "banana"
        }
    ],
    "vegetable": [
        {
            "id": "001",
            "name": "carrot"
        },{
            "id": "002",
            "name": "broccoli"
        },{
            "id": "003",
            "name": "green beans"
        }
    ]
}"""

jsonobj = json.loads(json_string)

def get_item(desired_type, desired_id):
    for item in jsonobj[desired_type]:
        if item["id"] == desired_id:
            return item["name"]
    return "not found"

print("My", desired_type, "'s name is:", get_item(desired_type, desired_id))
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'parses'

Comment: @KingGeedorah oh dear, have my Python skills got that rusty … thanks for the tip, fixed it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse the original string with `json.loads` and then process it like a normal dictionary.

I give you a fully functional example that resolves your concrete problem.

```py
import json

# functions definition

def parse_json_payload(payload: str):
    """
    Returns a object from string json payload
    """
    parsed = json.loads(original_str)
    return parsed


def extract_desired_type(object: dict,desired_type: str):
    """
    Returns de desired object type
    """
    return object[desired_type]


def extract_desired_id(objects, id: str):
    """
    Returns the desired object id if exists.
    If not, returns empty object
    """
    for element in objects:
        if element["id"] == id:
            return element

    return {}

# main
original_str = """{
    "fruit": [
        {
        "id": "001",
        "name": "apple"
    },{
        "id": "002",
        "name": "orange"
    },{
        "id": "003",
        "name": "banana"
    }
    ],
    "vegetable": [
        {
        "id": "001",
        "name": "carrot"
    },{
        "id": "002",
        "name": "broccoli"
    },{
        "id": "003",
        "name": "green beans"
    }
    ]
    }
"""

def show_example_1():
    # Extract fruit with id 001
    body = parse_json_payload(original_str)
    type_object = extract_desired_type(body, "fruit")
    object = extract_desired_id(type_object,"001")
    print(object)

def show_example_2():
    # Extract vegetable with id 002
    body = parse_json_payload(original_str)
    type_object = extract_desired_type(body, "vegetable")
    object = extract_desired_id(type_object,"002")
    print(object)


show_example_1()
print("\n\n")
show_example_2()
```

Output example:

```
python3 json_parser.py
{'id': '001', 'name': 'apple'}



{'id': '002', 'name': 'broccoli'}
```